# Case syntax with VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying evaluate each cell and if the value in A is 01,06,42,66 and the value in B is Outside, then DoStuff.

With the following case statement, it only picks up 66 not the rest. I could write a case statement for each combination, but that would be too much. Do you have any suggestions on how to simplify this?

```
Select Case .Range("A" & i).Value A & .Range("B" & i).Value 
Case "01","06","42","66" & "Outside" 
    DoStuff
End Select
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put an if in your Select Case:

```
Select Case .Range("A" & i).Value    
Case "01","06","42","66"
    If .Range("B" & i).Value = "Outside" Then
        DoStuff
    End If
End Select
```

Or you will need to concatenate all choices:

```
Select Case .Range("A" & i).Value  & .Range("B" & i).Value 
Case "01Outside","06Outside","42Outside","66Outside"
    DoStuff
End Select
```